# FFMPEG how to increase the volume of copied audio?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I‘m combining video A.mp4 and B.mp4, producing video C.mp4, using A.mp4's audio:

```sh
                ffmpeg \
                -i  A.mp4 \
                -i B.mp4 \
                -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[v_wide];[v_wide][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[out_video]" \
                -map "[out_video]" \
                -c:v libx265 \
                -crf 28 \
                -map 0:a:0 \
                -c:a copy -y \
                ./C.mp4
```

But due to some reason, the audio of A.mp4 is too quiet, so I use the following procedure to increase its DB:

```sh
        ffmpeg -i C.mp4 -af volume=20dB -c:v libx265 C_high_volume.mp4
```

The question is, can I combine the two steps into one (i.e. increasing the audio volume while coping it to C.mp4) so that I can save some processing time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bunch both filterchains together with `;` separator as one big filtergraph:

```
ffmpeg \
 -i A.mp4 -i B.mp4 \
 -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[v];[v][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[out_video];[0:a]volume=20dB[out_audio]" \
 -map [out_video] -c:v libx265 -crf 28 \
 -map [out_audio] -c:a aac \
 -y \
 C_high_volume.mp4
```

You must re-encode audio (I put `aac` for illustration)

edit: you can use one chain for the video

Comment: It is correct that we can put `volume=20dB` in the filter chain. The problem I find is that, if I use one chain for the video, as suggested by you, the result video is not the same as my old code. For example, if `A.mp4` is 1280*720, `B.mp4` is 1280*720, if using my old code, `C.mp4` is 2560*720 but your suggested code produces 1280*720.

Comment: Surprised to hear that there are difference. But, yeah, use the triple chain if it works.

Comment: @NameNull - use edited cmd.

Comment: @Gyan - (Thank you taking over the Windows build hosting! A little old news but I was concerned when the original host decided to stop.) Anyway, do you have any insight to why my original 2-chain suggestion didn't work in his case? Ever since I learned that "injection" trick, I've been using it without any issues. So, I'm curious.

Comment: @kesh Unlabeled filter outputs are routed after labeled inputs. So, in your syntax, [1:v] is the overlay base and the padded input is the overlay input.

Comment: @Gyan - Oh, so I had it backwards. Thanks for clarification